# Client Disabled Push Notifications on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If the client disabled push notifications, can he still receive notifications while the app is running? I read somewhere that if the notification doesn't specify "aps" as the namespace, it'll still go through despite the fact that push notifications have been disabled. The notifications of course will not appear if the app isn't in the foreground.  I can't find the article so I can't say for sure this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this, nope. Push notifications for active app status will not go through if push notifications are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If your client has disabled push notification in the app you should check this and alert him that your app may not run as expected only till he will enable push notifications again.

Comment: yeah but I'm wondering if push notifications can still go through. my messaging feature relies on push notifications for instant messaging.